# How do get matplotlib pyplot to generate a chart for viewing / output to .png at a specific resolution?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm fed up with manually creating graphs in excel and consequently, I'm trying to automate the process using Python to massage the .csv data into a workable form and matplotlib to plot the result.

Using matplotlib and generating them is no problem but I can't work out is how to set the aspect ration / resolution of the output.

Specifically, I'm trying to generate scatter plots and stacked area graphs. Everything I've tried seems to result in one or more of the following:

- Cramped graph areas (small plot area covered with the legend, axes etc.).
- The wrong aspect ratio.
- Large spaces on the sides of the chart area (I want a very wide / not very tall image).

If anyone has some working examples showing how to achieve this result I'd be very grateful!

Comment: But it's graphs are so easy / perdy! ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can control the aspect ratio with `ax.set_aspect`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax=fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax.set_aspect(0.3)
x,y=np.random.random((2,100))
plt.scatter(x,y)
```

Another way to set the aspect ratio (already mentioned by [jterrace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8143439/how-do-get-matplotlib-pyplot-to-generate-an-chart-for-viewing-output-to-png-a/8143596#8143596)) is to use the `figsize` parameter in `plt.figure`: e.g. `fig = plt.figure(figsize=(3,1))`. The two methods are slightly different however: A figure can contain many axes. `figsize` controls the aspect ratio for the entire figure, while `set_aspect` controls the aspect ratio for a particular axis.

Next, you can trim unused space from around the plot with `bbox_inches='tight'`:

```
plt.savefig('/tmp/test.png', bbox_inches='tight')
```

[image]

If you want to get rid of the excess empty space due to matplotlib's automated choice of x-range and y-range, you can manually set them with `ax.set_xlim` and `ax.set_ylim`:

```
ax.set_xlim(0, 1)
ax.set_ylim(0, 1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

### Aspect Ratio / Graph Size

The easiest way I've found to do this is to set the `figsize` parameter to the [figure](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.figure) function when creating the figure. For example, this would set the figure to be 4 inches wide by 3 inches tall:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4,3))
```

### Adjusting Spacing

For this, there is a function called [subplots_adjust](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.subplots_adjust) that allows you to change the bounding region of the graph itself, leaving more room for the title, axes, and labels. Here's an example from one of my graphs:

```
plt.gcf().subplots_adjust(bottom=0.15, left=0.13, right=0.95, top=0.96)
```

Answer (score 0):

For resolution, you can use the dpi (dots per inch) argument when creating a figure, or in the `savefig()` function. For high quality prints of graphics `dpi=600` or more is recommended.

Comment: The problem with upping the DPI is that it scales all of the line thicknesses & fonts with that dimension :-/